# Python TensorFlow: 'Sequential' object has no attribute 'Dense'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, google-colaboratory

I'm new to Neural Networks and am using google colab to build a Neural Network. but "'Sequential' object has no attribute 'Dense'" keeps showing up, I've tried using only Keras and not mix the libraries. Below lies my code, please help me, at this point I'm quite desperate.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Flatten, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Dropout, Dense
from keras import layers
from keras.utils import to_categorical
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.style.use('fivethirtyeight')

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, (5,5), activation='relu', input_shape=(32,32,3)))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2,2)))
model.add(Conv2D(32, (5,5), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2,2)))

model.add(Flatten())
model.Dense(1000, activation='relu')
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.Dense(500, activation='relu')
model.add(Droptout(0.5))
model.Dense(250, activation='relu')
model.Dense(10, activation='softmax')
```

Answer (score 2):

instead of using

> model.Dense(1000, activation='relu')

use

> model.add(Dense(1000, activation='relu'))

Answer (score 0):

It should be model.add(Dense(...)) rather than model.Dense